# HTML5 Style of iframe

Tags: css, html, iframe

I have an iframe, and I want to set the style inside attribute srcdoc using only CSS.

```
<iframe name="myFrame" srcdoc="<span>Hi</span>"> </iframe>
```

Is it possible to set the style of span inside srcdoc without using inline style but only style sheet?

If not, I can only put the whole html coding inside srcdoc to change the style?

Answer (score 0):

You could try to do it with Javascript by changing the attribute. I am not sure if that is a possible solution for you. But if it is, create a function that can dynamically change the attribute to whatever you want. That way you don't have add it statically inline.

I will give you an quick example below.

```
document.getElementsByTagName("iframe")[0].setAttribute("srcdoc", "demoValue");
```

And to change the style of the inner span all you have to do is assign it an id. And make a rule in your CSS, this will alow you to manipulate it both in Js and CSS.

If the iframe is not in the same domain you will not be able to modify the content client side. You will have to read the page using PHP and echo it from your domain.

Comment: I am afraid that only CSS can be used but not JS :(

Comment: That is still good, just add a id to the span. This will alow you to manipulate it when rendered with css rules. Maybe clear the question a little so I can try to help you more.

Comment: I just want to set style to the tag <span> inside srcdoc with using only CSS external or internal style sheet but not inline style. But even I used the id inside <span>, there is nothing changed

Comment: If the iframe is not in the same domain you will not be able to modify the content client side. You will have to read the page using PHP and echo it from your domain.

Answer (score 0):

CSS styles of an iframe are independent from main page appearance. And it is not possible to manipulate externally its design.

Relating to `srcdoc` attribute, I do not understand what you want. About it, [MDN says](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/iframe#attr-srcdoc): "This attribute is expected to generally be used together with the `sandbox` attribute".

Comment: I want to put something inside iframe without using a new page, therefore I use srcdoc.

Comment: `srcdoc` replaces whole content. It seems to be that you will have to modify the referenced HTML.